# Как получить id последнего значения в Google Sheets?

Tags: python, google-spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

У меня есть код который записывает данные в гугл таблицу. Дело в том, что я хочу записывать данные в конец таблицы. Пробовал через append, но почему-то все записывалось в один столбец, хотя я указывал другой диапазон

```
 sheet.values().append(
     spreadsheetId=sheet_id,
     range="Лист2!A1",
     valueInputOption="RAW",
     # insertDataOption="INSERT_ROWS",
     body={'values' : 'что-то там'}).execute()

 sheet.values().append(
     spreadsheetId=sheet_id,
     range="Лист2!B1",
     valueInputOption="RAW",
     # insertDataOption="INSERT_ROWS",
     body={'values' : 'что-то там'}).execute()

 sheet.values().append(
     spreadsheetId=sheet_id,
     range="Лист2!C1",
     valueInputOption="RAW",
     # insertDataOption="INSERT_ROWS",
     body={'values' : 'что-то там'}).execute()
```

Поэтому я решил что буду использовать *batchUpdate* т.к он делает один запрос на три поля сразу. Но мне при этом нужно знать id последней ячейки, чтобы записанные данные через *batchUpdate* не наложились поверх уже имеющихся. Как мне это сделать?